# Implement the alarm functionality in iOS

Tags: ios, ios8

The requirement for my app is to implement the alarm functionality within my app to remind the user appropriately
I had earlier implemented this using - UILocalNotification but it does not quite function as intended 
Is there any other way to implement the Alarm functionality in iOS other than using local notifications ?

Comment: First elaborate what is not working with your implementation of UILocalNotification, and then ask for other suggestions.

Comment: Please be specific with your problem what you are facing. Your question is too broad to answer. **UILocalNotification doesn't  quite function** what do you mean by this line ? You need to tell your problem here rather than whole application requirement. Hope You Understand!